# How to refocus on input element after reloading html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few input html elements. On change event (tab-out) of input im making a ajax post and get back html. and then i replace the existing html with this new html. Doing so looses the focus on next input element. 
However before i make the ajax post im storing id of the currently focused element so that i can refocus the same input after html is replaced. But its not working

below is my code

```
<div id="mycontainer">
    <input id="input1" />
    <input id="input2" />
    <input id="input3" />
</div>


$(function () {
     $("input").change(function () {
        $.ajax(
            {
                data: "somedata",
                url: "someurl",
                method: "POST"
            })
            .done(function (response) {
                    var currentElement = $(':focus').attr("id");
                    $("#mycontainer").html(response)
                    $("#" + currentElement).focus();
                })
    })
})
```

Comment: Change event fires after the blur event, so focus has moved. Did you debug and check what `currentElement` is? By the way, replacing all HTML is a bad idea, you lose handlers, focus, scroll position...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change event fires after the blur event, so focus has moved. If you want to focus on the element that was changed, you can use `event.target` to get a reference to the input that changed.

```
$("input").change(function (event) {
      $.ajax({
            data: "somedata",
            url: "someurl",
            method: "POST"
        }) .done(function (response) {
               var currentElement = event.target.id;
                $("#mycontainer").html(response)
                $("#" + currentElement).focus();
        });
})
```

If you want focus to remain where it is, your code should work, here's the proof.

```js
const HTML = `
    <input id="input1" />
    <input id="input2" />
    <input id="input3" />
`;

$(() => {
  $("input").change(() => {
    // Add async code to fake ajax
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(HTML), 100);
    }).then(response => {
      const currentElement = $(':focus').attr("id");
      $("#mycontainer").html(response)
      $("#" + currentElement).focus();
    });
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mycontainer">
  <input id="input1" />
  <input id="input2" />
  <input id="input3" />
</div>
```

However, as mentioned in my comment, this is poor approach because you lose the handlers, so you'll have to reset the handlers too and maybe scroll position. To avoid this, you can make your AJAX return data and update only the bits that need to be updated.

Comment: This get's the focus back to the changed input after ajax load and not to the newly focused input.

Comment: @BulentVural Well, if the OP wants to focus the new input, the existing code should work, added an explanation.

Comment: Then I upvote your answer @Juan :) Also thanks for the remarks on the bottom of your answer which would be the best approach to solve this kind of requirements.

Answer (score 1):

When you click somewhere on the page (including the button / link that loads your ajax content), the clicked element immediately takes the focus. So just before changing the html, it is already too late to store the focused id. You need to store it on focus change instead.

**Edit:**
Since there is no 'click' involved in the OP's question, I'm proposing an updated version of the above solution: Storing the changed input and running ajax stuff in focus handler.

```js
let changedInput;
$(document).on('focus', 'input', function() {
  if (changedInput) {
    // do whatever with changedInput.val() needed here
    changedInput = null;
    const currentElement = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        data: "somedata",
        url: "someurl",
        method: "POST"
      })
      .done(function(response) {
        $("#mycontainer").html(response);
        $("#" + currentElement).focus();
      })
  }

});

$(document).on('change', 'input', function() {
  changedInput = this;
})



/* BEGIN FAKE AJAX STUFF
 *
 */
let counter = 0;
$.ajax = function(params) {
  $('#msg').text("Fake AJAX Loading...");
  return {
    done: function(cb) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#msg').text("");
        cb(`
      <div id="mycontainer">
        <input value="${counter}" id="input1" />
        <input value="${counter}" id="input2" />
        <input value="${counter++}" id="input3" />
      </div>
      `);
      }, 300);
    }
  }
}
/* END FAKE AJAX STUFF */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:20px;" id="msg"></div>
<div id="mycontainer">
  <input value="" id="input1" />
  <input value="" id="input2" />
  <input value="" id="input3" />
</div>
```

Comment: This probably works but can be simpler, see my answer

Comment: I dont want the focus to be on the  element that was changed, instead it   remain where it is